# Is it even possible to configure both oauth2 and basic authentication for separate endpoints in same project?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I have a project in spring boot. I have configured Oauth2 to protect some rest endpoints and some are left without any authentication.

Is it possible to implement basic authentication for those endpoints, as I don't want to protect those with Oauth2.

I have some endpoints for end user and some for admin.

Hope all this make sense.

Comment: it's not clear why you need two authentication mechanisms to distinguish between 2 roles. Usually you use `@Secured` or `@RoleAllowed` for declarative role management per method. (also see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security )

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple entry points in http security by overriding http security by defining their orders please see below link

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Or if just need to manage some end points then you can even also manage in same http security configuration

Like

If end point this and has role something then httpbasic

And anyRequest. Authorize

If you can share your current http security configuration and let us know example end point you want to use http security then I can check